# Create .sh file

Tags: shell, sh

When I create .sh file, I need to give permission for him to be executed, there is a file that can be configured or command applied so I can already create the file with permission of execution?

Comment: .sh files are female.  Or gender neutral.  Definitely not correct to refer to it as "him".

Answer (score 0):

Through Terminal, type in this command:

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

To execute the command, do:

```
./file.sh
```

If you want an application, you can make an Automator using the previous commands.